# ReactJS 16.4 and Material UI 4.x compatibility

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am using React 16.4.1 and metrial-ui 4.1.1 and when i tried to run it locally i am getting the following Error.

```
TypeError: _react.default.memo is not a function
createSvgIcon
c:/apps/projects/app/node_modules/@material-ui/icons/utils/createSvgIcon.js:17
  14 | var _SvgIcon = _interopRequireDefault(require("@material-ui/core/SvgIcon"));
```

And the node and npm versions i have locally (on windows) are 10.16.0 and 6.9.0

When i build the same using Jenkins (running on linux) with node 10.13.0 and npm 6.9.1 it is running fine.

Not sure why such a minor version mismatches are causing this issue.

Thanks
Sateesh

Comment: Not sure how it's working for you on Linux, maybe Jenkins is pulling in the latest React or something, but according to [official migration guide](https://material-ui.com/guides/migration-v3/) for MUI v4 - `the minimum required version of React was increased from _react@^16.3.0_ to _react@^16.8.0_`

Comment: i suggest to run `npm update`, it'd be better if you're not using version control to take a copy of package.json before running it

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, React.memo was released in `react@16.6.0` [source](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/10/23/react-v-16-6.html).

It appears that `@material-ui/core@4.0.0` (even before 4.1.1) requires `react@16.8.0` [source](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v4.0.0/packages/material-ui/package.json#L34).

For what it's worth, there shouldn't be much difficulty in upgrading your React version to even the latest version. The biggest pain point will be if you use a library like `enzyme` (or other dependencies that try to keep up with exact API parity). You'd need to also update that and it's partnering dependencies.