# react.default.memo is not a function at createSvgIcon

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, material-ui

I've updated my Material-UI version to 1.0.0, but I'm having this strange error that

```
_react.default.memo is not a function
    at createSvgIcon
```

I've done a little research and they say to downgrade the react redux library to 6.0.0, so I've done this but the error persists. The dependencies are these:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/codemod": "^4.5.0",
    "@material-ui/core": "^1.0.0",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.5.1",
    "@material-ui/styles": "^4.7.1",
    "babel-polyfill": "~6.22.0",
    "browser-filesaver": "~1.1.1",
    "build-url": "~1.2.0",
    "es6-promise": "~4.2.5",
    "file-saver": "~2.0.1",
    "iban": "~0.0.8",
    "immutable": "~3.8.2",
    "jsdoc": "^3.6.3",
    "jsdoc-api": "~3.0.0",
    "loaders.css": "~0.1.2",
    "material-ui": "^0.20.2",
    "moment": "~2.20.1",
    "prop-types": "~15.6.0",
    "react": "~16.3.0",
    "react-datepicker": "~0.48.0",
    "react-dom": "~16.2.0",
    "react-feature-toggles": "~3.0.3",
    "react-intl": "~2.4.0",
    "react-loaders": "~3.0.1",
    "react-redux": "~6.0.0",
    "react-router": "~3.2.0",
    "react-tooltip": "~3.10.0",
    "redux": "~3.7.2",
    "redux-form": "~6.8.0",
    "redux-form-material-ui": "~4.3.3",
    "redux-immutable": "~4.0.0",
    "redux-persist": "~4.8.0",
    "redux-persist-immutable": "~4.3.1",
    "redux-saga": "~0.15.3",
    "whatwg-fetch": "~2.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "~6.26.0",
    "babel-eslint": "~7.1.1",
    "babel-loader": "~7.1.2",
    "babel-plugin-istanbul": "~3.1.2",
    "babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread": "~6.26.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "~6.23.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "~6.22.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "~6.22.0",
    "chai": "~3.5.0",
    "cross-env": "~6.0.3",
    "css-loader": "~0.26.0",
    "enzyme": "~3.6.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "~1.5.0",
    "enzyme-react-intl": "~1.4.5",
    "enzyme-redux": "~0.1.8",
    "eslint": "~3.19.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "~14.1.0",
    "eslint-loader": "~1.6.1",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "~2.2.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "~4.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "~6.9.0",
    "exports-loader": "~0.6.3",
    "file-loader": "~0.10.1",
    "html-loader": "~0.4.4",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "~2.28.0",
    "ignore-styles": "~5.0.1",
    "imports-loader": "~0.7.0",
    "istanbul": "~0.4.5",
    "jsdom": "~9.8.3",
    "jsdom-global": "~2.1.0",
    "json-loader": "~0.5.4",
    "mocha": "~5.0.1",
    "node-sass": "~4.13.0",
    "nyc": "~14.1.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "~16.5.2",
    "redux-saga-testing": "~1.0.5",
    "redux-test-utils": "~0.1.3",
    "sass-loader": "~4.1.1",
    "sinon": "~2.2.0",
    "style-loader": "~0.13.1",
    "webpack": "~3.10.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "~2.11.1"
  },
```

Do you know why this error occurs?

Comment: Try to use the last version of react, redux and react-redux.  Also check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56811531/reactjs-16-4-and-material-ui-4-x-compatibility

Answer (score 1):

In your dependencies, you are using the latest version of `@material-ui/icons` (v4.5.1). This version uses `React.memo` in [createSvgIcon](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v4.7.2/packages/material-ui-icons/src/utils/createSvgIcon.js#L5). `React.memo` was [introduced in React 16.6](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/10/23/react-v-16-6.html), but you are using version 16.3 of React.

My recommendation would be to go to the latest version of React (16.12.0 for `react` and `react-dom`). This will give you more flexibility in which versions of other libraries you can leverage. At a minimum, you should upgrade React to at least 16.8 since the current versions of many libraries are dependent on React hooks.